# Can't fetch my magento 2.3.3 data with graphql

Tags: magento, graphql

I'm pretty new to magento but I get used to it. I want to retrieve some product data from my local server but it doesn't want to fetch with graphql in any way, I can't find a way to know if I have to activate it,

I tried to look for tutorials on how use it on magento 2 but it keeps giving me results for custom modules. The data I want to retrieve is NOT custom. It works well on the production website but my local server won't allow it.

I'm using graphiql to test if it works but nothing does... I'm using the following query and using typical endpoint (as all the tutorials tell you to)

```
{ cmsPage(
    id:2
  ) {
    title
  }
}
```

What it returns on GraphIQL with endpoint http://www.myserver.local/graphql:

```
TypeError: Failed to fetch
```

What I expect it to be :

```
{
  "errors": [
    {
      "message": "The CMS page with the \"2\" ID doesn't exist.",
      "category": "graphql-no-such-entity",
      "locations": [
        {
          "line": 1,
          "column": 3
        }
      ],
      "path": [
        "cmsPage"
      ]
    }
  ],
  "data": {
    "cmsPage": null
  }
}
```

Thanks for your time, hope you can find it